# Mirror Checkbox checked status

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have two sets of checkboxes, All Terms and Popular Terms. Some of the terms will appear in both lists and be either checked or unchecked.

I need to be able to make sure the matching term in either group matches the selection status of the other. So if Mobile is deselected in the Popular group, it should be deselected in the All group.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('#chassischecklist li :checkbox, #chassischecklist-pop li :checkbox').on( 'click', function(){
var t = $(this), c = t.is(':checked'), id = t.val();        
$('#chassischecklist li :checkbox, #chassischecklist-pop li :checkbox').prop('checked',false);
$('#in-chassis-' + id + ', #in-popular-chassis-' + id).prop( 'checked', c );
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FtJuR/

Comment: There are couple of mistakes, please check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form your demo fiddle, I found that there are many errors. Please try to avoid them.

1. you are giving the same `id` to the checkboxes under the different lists. For example, there are two check boxes with id `in-chassis-57` one in all list and another in popular list.
2. you are retrieving the value of the check box in varaible `id` and trying to get the element using the id and there is no element with that id.
   id = t.val()

Check the working [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FtJuR/2/).

Comment: Looks like it works, except for when selecting or deselecting items in the Popular Group it doesn't change the All Group.

Comment: Oh sorry, it is becausse of the `id`. Check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FtJuR/3/)